# Screen Resolution on FS Lifebook E8110 Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: display, resolution, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 on an Fujitsu Siemens Liefebook E8110, installing went fine, but the maximum resolution is 1024x768, although the Screen should support 1400x1050 or at least 1280x1024.

On my last Version there was a file xorg.conf (/etc/X11/xorg.conf), it's not there anymore, so I suppose the changed the way to configure x.org. Inside the Computer is a Intel Mobile 945GM graphics card, as far as I know.

How can I have a higher resolution?

Comment: perhaps the video driver?

Comment: Intel Graphic Cards drivers normally are very well detected. At least in older Ubuntu and this card is quite old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the exact type of your Laptop Series, some Models of this series just support 1024x768 as a resolution.